# WooCommerce function not working correctly after moving from the functions.php into a class

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I've a problem with my child theme. I first had all my stuff and hooks for WooCommerce inside my child themes `function.php` file. Everything worked fine until I moved it into a class which get's loaded with an autoloader. For example I've added custom notices when a user saves the account details page:

```
<?php

namespace App;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Account class
 */
class Account {
    /**
     * @var Account
     */
    private static ?Account $instance = null;

    /**
     * Get instance of class
     *
     * @return Account
     */
    public static function get_instance(): Account {
        if ( self::$instance === null ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->register();
    }
    private function register(): void {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', [ $this, 'save_edit_account_form' ], 12, 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Save account form
     *
     * @param $user_id int
     */
    public function save_edit_account_form( $user_id ): void {
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( 'Test' ); //Gets no longer displayed anymore

        exit( wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'settings' )  ) );
    }
}
```

I'm just loading the class in my `functions.php` file like this:

```
Account::get_instance();
```

I can verify that the class get's loaded and the hook get's fired. There are no error messages. I'm just expecting this output on my account page like before moving the hook and everything into my class.

When I put the hook directly into my `functions.php` file of my child theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_edit_account_form', 12, 1 );
function save_edit_account_form( $user_id ): void {
    wc_clear_notices();
    wc_add_notice( 'Test' );

    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'settings' ) );
    exit;
}
```

But putting everything into my `functions.php` would end in 90000+ lines of code. Thats why I created classes for a lot of my functions.

Does someone has an idea why this happens?

Comment: You don't have to create classes to clean up your `functions.php`, only create classes if you intend to do object oriented programming. Using classes doesn't mean the code is OOP, especially if you're trying to use the singleton anti-pattern ( aka the `get_instance()` static method that tries to make sure only 1 instance of that object is ever available ). Just move your existing hook/function from `functions.php` into another file that's named appropriatley. There's no need for classes here

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, object orientation is also a reason. So it would be nice if there is a solution for this kind of development because I've already created a lot of them... So it would be not so helpful going back to the roots.

Comment: I see no way to make this code OOP, it's just using a class being used as a makeshift namespace, your original function would be best practice here. OOP isn't shunting everything into classes, and not everything has to be an object. If I had to guess, I'd place suspicion on the use of the `private` keyword here, but, again, it was a mistake to change this to a `class`, and it is not OOP, nor does what you're trying to do fit into true OOP. Especially since you can't have more than one account.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the session... don't know how to fix this.